# How to ignore/mock Slf4j log lines?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, logback, slf4j

I upgraded Spring Boot from 2.5.10 to 2.5.12 and it brought a breaking change for me in logback https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.5.11

A few of my unit tests (using Mockito) are breaking with NullPointerException where I am passing a mocked exception to the log lines in the main code.
For example, this is a log line that I have in my main code, and the class is annotated with lombok's @Slf4j

```java
log.warn("Exception occurred while doing something", exception);
```

Earlier, this log line was not throwing any errors.

My intention here is to not mock the logger, but to ignore this line through whatever workaround possible (even if I have to mock it).

Lombok adds the following on compilation (not sure if mocking would work here):

```java
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
```

One workaround I have is to not use mocked exceptions and pass an actual exception but that's going to take the fun out of unit tests.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:99)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.warn(Logger.java:692)
    at com.example.r.e.d.s.d.t.HelloWorld.executeInternal(HelloWorld.java:74)
    at com.example.r.e.d.s.d.t.HelloWorldTest.testLocksOnDomain(HelloWorldTest.java:94)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Moreover, with my unit tests working with the previous library version. There was a problem that during the execution of the unit tests, it used to print logs like WARN and ERROR in the console (which sometimes created a lot of confusion).

Comment: You probably can't ignore this line directly in code unless you wrap the statement with a `if(logger.isEnabled(Level.WARN)) { ... }` and disable this logger in your tests (either specifically or more generally on a package/severity/general level). However, if you disable the loggers in your tests the logger itself should not do much beyond this statement and the statement itself doesn't look like it could throw a NPE. Care to share some details on where exactly this happens, i.e. the stacktrace?

Comment: added stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line responsible for the error (in the version that you mentioned) looks like this (see https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/v_1.2.11/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ThrowableProxy.java#L99):

```
if (throwableSuppressed.length > 0) {
```

It's worth noting that there's a fix for your issue, although I have no idea what version of Logback might have it now or in the future. https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/c34645b320d2b31ccaf0de9bb079391904352a28 contains the following relevant change:
Replaced

```
if (throwableSuppressed.length > 0) {
```

with

```
// while JDK's implementation of getSuppressed() will always return a non-null array,
// this might not be the case in mocked throwables. We are being extra defensive here.
if (OptionHelper.isNotEmtpy(throwableSuppressed)) {
```

I'm generally not super keen on mocking Exceptions, myself. But if that's what your context demands, then mocking getSuppressed() to return a non-null (probably empty is fine) array might solve the issue.

Comment: Yeah. `when(myMockedException.getSuppressed()).thenReturn(new Throwable[0]);` does work. But is there a way to not execute the line at all. So that no [WAN], [ERROR], [INFO], etc. are printed during the execution of the unit test?

Comment: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#rootElement leads me to believe that you can configure Logback to disable logging completely:
"The value of the level attribute can be one of the case-insensitive strings TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, ALL or OFF."
I have no idea what side-effects that may have, or even whether it would actually solve your problem.